# Is there any JPA implementation work well with Sqlite database?

Tags: hibernate, sqlite, jpa

As far as I know Hibernate doesn't work very well with sqlite, due to the lack of official provided "SqliteDialect".
Is there any other JPA implementation works better with it?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045405/are-there-any-good-orms-preferably-jpa-implementations-that-support-sqlite-on Mentions Android but should still be applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your goal is, but if you're looking for an embedded data storage library with JPA-style persistence, your best bet is using [Berkeley DB Java Edition](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/index-093405.html) with the [Data Persistence Layer API](http://bit.ly/dSkUS7). There's an interesting article on how to convert SQL queries to the DPL [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/performing.pdf). Basically, using the DPL to access Berkeley DB Java Edition is about 10x faster than using Hibernate to access an RDBMS.

Disclaimer: I'm the product manager for Berkeley DB, so I'm a little biased. That said, we have lots of Java application developers who chose BDB JE because it's small, fast, scalable, reliable and the API is a natural fit for their application development environment.

Comment: Thank you for you advice, and I will try Berkeley DB and DPL soon.

Comment: And how about the overall size of Berkeley DB comparing to the other embedded database?

Comment: @zbdiablo, Berkeley DB compiles in under a MB. That's much smaller than any of the RDBMS products. As someone said to me recently, "Transactions, Recovery, Replication and DPL in under a MB. Cool!" :-)

Comment: The second link doesn't seem to go to where you intend any more.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [OrmLite](http://ormlite.com/), a lightweight ORM tool for persisting java objects.

Comment: It's not 100% JPA compliant though. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187304/why-ormlite-has-its-own-annotations