# Are there Android tools that assist in creating content providers?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I see that there are many options for ORM tools:
[Any good ORM tools for Android development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371538/any-good-orm-tools-for-android-development)

But do any of them help you to create Content Providers quickly?

If not, what tools exist?

Answer (score 2):

you can also have a look at CPOrm on github: https://github.com/Wackymax/CPOrm

It will create the database and content provider for you and handles all of the boiler plate code for common database operations via the content provider.

Answer (score 0):

Try [MOTODEV](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/motodevstudio/features/) Studio for Android.It has a Database Management feature to conveniently view and edit SQLite databases on emulated devices.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at this project: https://github.com/groupme/ProviderOne
It claims ability to generate "all you need" just from DB file