# Error with inserting data into sqlite database

Tags: android, database

I'm trying to insert data into SqLite database by using a dialog wrapper. However, I am unable to do so. I have 2 texts called Title and Template to insert into the database. But it crashes. 
Below is my java code:
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        menu.add(0,MENU_ITEM_INSERT,0,R.string.menu_insert);
        return true;
    }

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case MENU_ITEM_INSERT:
            insert();
            //startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT,getIntent().getData()));
            return true;
    }
    return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}

@Override 
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu,View v,ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;
    try {
         info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "bad menuInfo", e);
        return;
    }

    mCursor = (Cursor) getListAdapter().getItem(info.position);

    menu.setHeaderTitle(mCursor.getString(COLUMN_INDEX_TITLE));

    menu.add(0,MENU_ITEM_DELETE,0 ,R.string.menu_delete);
    menu.add(1,MENU_ITEM_ADDTMESSAGE,1,R.string.menu_add);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;
    try {
         info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "bad menuInfo", e);
        return false;
    }

    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case MENU_ITEM_DELETE:
            //delete selected row
            delete(info.id);
            return true;
        case MENU_ITEM_ADDTMESSAGE:
            //ADD TO MESSAGE
            return true;
    }
    return(super.onContextItemSelected(item));
}

private void insert()
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View addView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.templates_editor,null);
    final DialogWrapper wrapper = new DialogWrapper(addView);

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle(R.string.menu_insert)
    .setView(addView)
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.item_ok,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            processInsert(wrapper);
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton(R.string.item_cancel,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // ignore, just dismiss
        }
    })
    .show();
}

private void delete(final long rowId)
{
    if(rowId > 0)
    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle(R.string.menu_delete)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.item_ok, 
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                processDelete(rowId);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.item_cancel,
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        //dismiss dialog
                                    }
                                }).show();
    }
}

private void processDelete(long rowId)
{
    String[] args = {String.valueOf(rowId)};

    db.getWritableDatabase().delete("Templates", Templates._ID, args);
    mCursor.requery();
}

private void processInsert(DialogWrapper wrapper)
{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put("title", wrapper.getTitle());
    cv.put("template", wrapper.getTemplate());

    db.getWritableDatabase().insert("Templates", "title", cv);
    db.getWritableDatabase().insert("Templates", "template", cv);
    mCursor.requery();
}

class DialogWrapper{
    EditText titleField = null;
    EditText templateField = null;
    View base = null;

    DialogWrapper(View base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    String getTitle(){
        return(getTitleField().getText().toString());
    }

    String getTemplate(){
        return(getTemplateField().getText().toString());            
    }

    private EditText getTitleField(){
        if(titleField == null){
            titleField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
        }
        return titleField;
    }

    private EditText getTemplateField(){
        if(templateField == null){
            templateField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.template);
        }
        return templateField;
    }
}
```

Below is my logCat:

12-02 08:23:17.712: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(204): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
12-02 08:23:17.862: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(204): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-02 08:23:17.862: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(204):     at joel.GroupSMS.TemplatesList$DialogWrapper.getTitle(TemplatesList.java:214)
12-02 08:23:17.862: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(204):     at joel.GroupSMS.TemplatesList.processInsert(TemplatesList.java:196)
12-02 08:23:17.862: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(204):     at joel.GroupSMS.TemplatesList.access$0(TemplatesList.java:192)
12-02 08:23:17.862: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(204):     at joel.GroupSMS.TemplatesList$1.onClick(TemplatesList.java:150)
12-02 08:23:17.862: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(204):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:158)
12-02 08:23:17.862: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(204):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-02 08:23:17.862: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(204):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-02 08:23:17.862: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(204):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
12-02 08:23:17.862: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(204):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-02 08:23:17.862: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(204):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-02 08:23:17.862: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(204):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
12-02 08:23:17.862: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(204):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
12-02 08:23:17.862: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(204):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

**Edit**
This is my stacktrace requested pertaining to my comment:

12-06 16:54:12.466: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=joel.GroupSMS/.TemplateEdit }
12-06 16:54:16.550: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(254): Shutting down VM
12-06 16:54:16.550: WARN/dalvikvm(254): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
12-06 16:54:16.550: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(254): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
12-06 16:54:16.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(254): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{joel.GroupSMS/joel.GroupSMS.TemplateEdit}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 16:54:16.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(254):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
12-06 16:54:16.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(254):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
12-06 16:54:16.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(254):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
12-06 16:54:16.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(254):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
12-06 16:54:16.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(254):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-06 16:54:16.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(254):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-06 16:54:16.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(254):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
12-06 16:54:16.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(254):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 16:54:16.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(254):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-06 16:54:16.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(254):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
12-06 16:54:16.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(254):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
12-06 16:54:16.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(254):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-06 16:54:16.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(254): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 16:54:16.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(254):     at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireProvider(ContentResolver.java:754)
12-06 16:54:16.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(254):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:197)
12-06 16:54:16.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(254):     at android.app.Activity.managedQuery(Activity.java:1495)
12-06 16:54:16.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(254):     at joel.GroupSMS.TemplateEdit.onCreate(TemplateEdit.java:77)
12-06 16:54:16.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(254):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-06 16:54:16.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(254):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without line numbers in your code to match the traceback but I'm guessing that `(EditText) findViewById(R.id.title)` is returning null. Check your app in hierarchyviewer at the time you're doing the insert and make sure the view you think is there in the hierarchy is actually there at the time you're processing the insert code.

Comment: You're pretty close. The line of error is at the "getTitleField". And yes, the view is at the hierarchy when processing the insert code. I think.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're bothering with the DialogWrapper at all; this isn't a view recycling in a list situation (where the 10% or so performance hit on finding a view by ID is worth caching); you should probably just be grabbing the editText's value when you need it by ID instead of bothering with an intermediary object. But in any case, try using dialog.findViewById(whatever) instead of just the Activity's findViewById(whatever), passing the dialog (instead of a wrapper) to your method.

Comment: DialogWrapper is just used for testing. If possible, I rather it to be linked to another layout and retrieve the data from the database and insert into the EditTexts.

Comment: how do i delete/insert/update data in database without using content provider like codes? can give me an example? Do i have to use URI? Hope you can help me.

Comment: mCursor = managedQuery(mUri, PROJECTION,null,null,null);
PROJECTION has 3 array items.
It seems that i have a nullpointerexception at this line. Any ideas?

Comment: if that's a new exception (looks like it, since the one you posted above never even gets to the database), post the traceback where you're getting that. Otherwise there's no way anyone could do anything but guess wildly.

Comment: i have provided the stacktrace in my edit section. Mind taking a look at it?

Comment: I'd log the hell out of it and figure out what's null that shouldn't be, but since you only gave the trace but not the code, who knows... the first obvious thing that you should have checked and logged at that point before posting, what's the value of mUri at the point you make that call?