# A good Java ORM library on Android

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, orm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any Good ORM tools for Android development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371538/any-good-orm-tools-for-android-development)

Any suggestions on a good ORM library that works with Android?

Comment: I never tire of search, but unfortunately it doesn't seem very popular on StackOverflow...

Comment: you are really polite, if i asked maybe i heaven't had good results, however thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can recommend https://www.activeandroid.com/

Comment: Tobias, Sorry for asking on a old thread. Does activeandroid cover nested class scenarios? Like, class Parent { Class[] Children children; }. In this Parent class has a reference array for Children class.