# Good ORM Tool for Android?

Tags: android, orm

I am looking to find a good ORM tool for android. Please give me your suggestions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any Good ORM tools for Android development?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371538/any-good-orm-tools-for-android-development)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ORMLite is one known tool for android ORM. Here is [site](http://ormlite.com/android/examples/) with couple of examples.

Comment: i found  some tools but i think ormlite is most developed tool.

Comment: was greenDAO mong other tools you gone through ? i am a bit confused about selection b/w ORMlite and greenDAO :(

Comment: definitevely ORMLite over GreenDao i've been using greenDao for so long but it's not very sofisticated, ORMLite is a real ORM and works for big data greenDao is fast true but it's intended for small databases and doesn't make it easy to use joint and stuff plus ....

Answer (score 1):

Apache Cayenne has something called [ROP](http://cayenne.apache.org/doc/remote-object-persistence-guide.html) that splits the ORM stack into server and client parts. The client part has been [ported to Android](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAY-1604), although currently you'd need to do some Java hacking to use it in the app, so it is not for everyone yet.