# Is there a way to generate Database handler based on a model class?

Tags: android, generator

I have a model class, let's call it "History":

```
public class History {

    int _id;
    String _file_name;
    String _full_path;
    String _file_type;

    public History(){
    }

    public History(int id, String _name, String _full_path, String _file_type){
        this._id = id;
        this._file_name = _name;
        this._full_path = _full_path;

 this._file_type = _file_type;

}
public int get_id() {
    return _id;
}
public void set_id(int _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}
public String get_file_name() {
    return _file_name;
}
public void set_file_name(String _file_name) {
    this._file_name = _file_name;
}
public String get_full_path() {
    return _full_path;
}
public void set_full_path(String _full_path) {
    this._full_path = _full_path;
}
public String get_file_type() {
    return _file_type;
}
public void set_file_type(String _file_type) {
    this._file_type = _file_type;
}

}
```

I'd like to auto-generate a Database Handler for all of my models that looks similar to this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "file_explorer";

    private static final String TABLE_HISTORY = "history";

    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_HISTORY + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_HISTORY);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

(This isn't a handler for my model, but you get the idea)

Is this possible or do I have to manually create a database handler for each model?

I checked Eclipse's auto generation options but I didn't find what I need.

Comment: I think you have to create it manually. I haven't seen a feature like that.

Comment: Perhaps http://code.google.com/p/sqlitegen/?

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not solve your problem, I think.

Comment: Maybe [http://code.google.com/p/3p-android-database-generator/](http://code.google.com/p/3p-android-database-generator/) this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this SO question: [Any good ORM tools for Android development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371538/any-good-orm-tools-for-android-development)

Although I would probably go with [ORMLite for Android](http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml). Examples for use are on the site.