# Android - What is wrong with Sqlite Date Query and how can i improve my coding style

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am getting error in my sql Query and what are things i need to change to improve my coding

My Code is

My DBHelper Code

```
public Cursor fetchDaysAppointment(String from, String to){

    Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+CUSTOMER_TABLE_NAME+
            "WHERE (aDate >= ? AND aDate <= ?)", 
            new String[]{from, to});

    if(c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
```

My Java Code

```
public void getDaysAppointment(int day, int month, int year){

    String from = year+"-"+month+"-"+day+" 00:00:00";
    String to = year+"-"+month+"-"+day+" 23:59:59";

    in.open();
    cursor = in.fetchDaysAppointment(from, to);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    for(int i=0; i<cursor.getCount(); i++){

        if(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("aTime")) == 8){
            System.out.println("Hi the value is found to be Matched");
        }
        cursor.moveToNext();

    }

}
```

Log  cat Error

```
02-14 17:23:06.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4535): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-14 17:23:06.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4535): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ashadegreen/com.example.ashadegreen.Home}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "(": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM customerWHERE (aDate >= ? AND aDate <= ?)
```

Comment: You forgot space before WHERE

Comment: if you want a review advice post on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add space before `WHERE`.

Comment: hey you r right....do you have any idea why this is not working...the value 8 exist in my tableif(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("aTime")) == 8){
    System.out.println("Hi the value is found to be Matched");
   }

Comment: if condition i am checking for value 8....why it is not working?

Comment: @user2065795 According to your aTime is a date, how can you call getInt on a column that have date? I guess, you should call cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("XXX")) where XXX is the name of the column which contains your value 8.

Answer (score 2):

*What are things i need to change to improve my coding.?*

One thing i see is that you are defining CUSTOMER_TABLE_NAME and others in your DBHelper class itself, for small programs that's fine, but when your code grows and the Database Schema becomes bigger, it is important to maintain code and db.

For that, make another class lets say named Constants, and define all your Database schema related information, like dbname, table's, their columns in that same class, and later you can access them using like **Constants."itemyouwanttouse"** . This will make your code a lot more organized.

Comment: Yeah it makes sense..Thks

Comment: Also please check question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371538/any-good-orm-tools-for-android-development