# Are there other ways to fetch data from the SQLite database except using Cursor?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I'm just interesting: can I use something else for retrieving data from the database instead of using `Cursor` like this:

```
Cursor fetch_ = database_.rawQuery("SELECT " + USER_ID + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
if (fetch_.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        String data_ = fetch_.getString(fetch_.getColumnIndex("userId"));
    } while (fetch_.moveToNext());
}
fetch_.close();
```

So are there some other ways? May be I can fetch data directly in Java data structures like `HashMap<>` or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use some ORM library, see: [Any good ORM tools for Android development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371538/any-good-orm-tools-for-android-development)

My personal favorite is `ActiveAndroid` library (https://www.activeandroid.com/)

See the documentation: https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki

---

For example

```
@Table(name = "Items")
public class Item extends Model {
    @Column(name = "Name")
    public String name;

    @Column(name = "Category")
    public Category category;
}
```

Fetching all should be like

```
List<Item> items = new Select().from(Item.class).execute();
```

Comment: `ActiveAndroid` seems interesting :D