# Using libraries in android project

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm starting with Android in Eclipse and i would like to use some libraries that i use in anothers Java Projects. See: Hibernate, JPA and SQLLite.

I putted the ".jar" files inside '/libs" directory and when i try to start my android application i got the following error:

```
[2014-11-21 14:49:46 - MyFirstApp] The library 'sqlite-jdbc-3.5.7.jar' contains native libraries that will not run on the device.
[2014-11-21 14:49:46 - MyFirstApp] The following libraries were found:
[2014-11-21 14:49:46 - MyFirstApp]  - native/linux/libsqlitejdbc.so
[2014-11-21 14:49:46 - MyFirstApp]  - native/mac/libsqlitejdbc.jnilib
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the log message suggests, Android won't be able to load the JAR file you have added as a dependency. You would need to use Android versions of the libraries you are trying to use. For `sqlite`, you could try [`SQLDroid`](https://github.com/SQLDroid/SQLDroid).

That being said, you may run into problems with the other JARs as well. I am not exactly sure how these dependencies fit in your application's architecture; but, you may find the discussions in [Any good ORM tools for Android development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371538/any-good-orm-tools-for-android-development) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to develop your android apps in Android Studio. Much better dependency manager, build system etc..

https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html