# Android development and hibernate+spring

Tags: java, android, spring, hibernate

I wanted to ask that Is hibernate and spring of no use to you if you learn android development or are an android developer?

Is hibernate and spring only for JavaSE or JavaEE?

If I learn android development do I need to learn hibernate and spring too?

Please help I am very confused :(

Comment: no you don't need to learn/use hibernate and spring with Android development.

Comment: Thank you...but if i already know spring n hibernate will it be of no use with android?

Comment: If you're interested in Spring and Hibernate - learn it, if you're not - don't learn it. Even though they're mostly irrelevant for Android, these frameworks illustrate a number of interesting ideas and patterns that should be interesting to any software developer.

Answer (score 4):

> I wanted to ask that Is hibernate and spring of no use to you if you learn android development or are an android developer?

What you want to use and what you don't, its all entirely up to you.

1. **Hibernate in Android** - You can use Hibernate in your application but its too much for Android, especially considering the size and number of dependencies. You can use light weight ORM tool like ORMLite. (visit this post for further reference - [Any good ORM tools for Android development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371538/any-good-orm-tools-for-android-development) )
2. **Spring in Android** - As far as implementing Spring in Android project is concerned, there is a separate framework known by the name of `Spring-Android` which you can implement in your android application. It is particularly useful for handling RESTful web services from your Android Application, working with HTTP requests etc... (Do visit: http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/ )